# trying to plot correlation

Tags: r, graphics, correlation

I have the following dataset for which I am trying to show between-column correlations

[image]

I am looking for output like this with my data I have tried corrplot but this does not give result with my data :

[image]

Comment: `corrplot::corrplot()`.

Answer (score 2):

You can make that diagram with the `corrplot()` function from the `corrplot` package.

```
library(corrplot)
mt_cor <- cor(mtcars)                  # builds correlation matrix
corrplot(mt_cor, type = "upper")       # without this, it would mirror about diagonal
```

[image]